# getPageTitle not being called in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout, fragmentpageradapter

I have a `FragmentPagerAdapter` which handles getting the current fragment, keeping track of the number of tabs and setting the tab title for each tab.

```
public class ClothingSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private String[] mCategories;

    public ClothingSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        mCategories = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ClothingCategoryFragment.newInstance(mCategories[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCategories.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Log.d("getPageTitle", mCategories[position]);
        return mCategories[position];
    }
}
```

In my activity I implement this class like so.

```
ClothingSectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter =
                new ClothingSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

sectionsPagerAdapter.setContext(this);
mViewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));
mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(startingFragmentPosition);
```

However when I run my app. The tabs are present but they are title-less. The `getPageTitle` method is never called. How do I fix this?

Comment: `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```